# What is the vertical line in Datadog APM trace

Tags: trace, metrics, datadog, telemetry, flamegraph

I'm not sure how to interpret the long vertical line in Datadog APM Traces
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That indicates the span was called asynchronously

This doc talks about python, but it's true if all languages:
https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/tracing-async-python-code/